# doctrine query language(DQL) createquery with LIMIT

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm

how to use `LIMIT` on DQL,

i have dql like this

```
$LampuOns = self::$em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM \Entities\Product\Category c WHERE id='{$Dataid}'")->execute();
```

when i added limit  like this

```
$LampuOns = self::$em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM \Entities\Product\Category c WHERE id='{$Dataid}' LIMIT = 1")->execute();
```

it returned error message. 
any have idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DQL Don't implement any limit clausole, look at [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/5409) for motivation.

So you must use  the Doctrine  [Query::setMaxResults()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only)

So somethings like:

```
$LampuOns = self::$em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM \Entities\Product\Category c WHERE id='{$Dataid}'");
$LampuOns->setMaxResult(1);
$LampuOns->execute();
```

Hope this help